# Stacked table column widths

Tags: genexus

You can use a GeneXus HTML table to layout text blocks and attributes. If I add a second table to contain some other information that I want to conditionally display, quite often, the first cell is a different width to the first cells of the table stacked above it.

How do you make all the columns/cells the same width so that stacked tables display with their contents correctly aligned?

This is for GeneXus Web in Evo 2 & 3.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: If i understand your question...
You can **statically** set the first cell width for each table in the form.
Additionally, you can **programmatically** switch the first cell width for each table.
Can you describe some example or image?

Comment: Hi, I've added an image (above). I'd like to get the Password/Confirm cells the same width as the Client details in the above table so it is all aligned. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a value in the `width` property of the client table first cell.
So, put the same value in the `width` property of the password table first cell.

Remember that the width value must be enough for both tables. In your case, the biggest textblock is the "Client Name". So, choose a width enough for that.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set a width, HTML will assume the minimum width required to accommodate the content. If you don't want it to be set automatically when when the page is displayed, you have to decide on a width.

In your case, you have to put the same width value for a cell (any cell) in the first column of both tables.